# submit button under my php class

Tags: php

I'm trying to add my `submit` button after calling my php class.

```
<?php 

include 'includes/calendar.php';
$calendar = new Calendar();
echo $calendar->show();

?>
<div class="text-center">
  <input id="no-change" class="btn btn-width bkgrnd-cyan" type="submit" name="user-form" value="Sign Up">
</div>
```

my submit button is showing up above the content of my class.

I tried to add my submit button inside the `php` and just `echo` the button but it didn't work.

Comment: This sounds like a styling issue, not a PHP issue.  What is the actual client-side markup?

Comment: @David yes I just realize that.  I could make it work by adding this to the button `style="position:relative;left:0px;top:380px;"`  However, I don't like this way because I feel that it might look different in others monitors..does this solution would look different in other monitors size?

Comment: It's impossible for anyone here to know your styling given the information provided.  A question about that, which supplies relevant information, could be meaningful.

Comment: the only `style` that I have and `html and css` is for my `button` the `text-center` is just `text-align: center` nothing else.  The button does appear in the `center` but above the php code...even if I onlye have `echo 'Hello'` inside my class that `Hello` is under my `submit` button

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap the tag around your php

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php 

include 'includes/calendar.php';
$calendar = new Calendar();
echo $calendar->show();

?>
</div>
<div class="text-center col-md-12">
  <input id="no-change" class="btn btn-width bkgrnd-cyan" type="submit" name="user-form" value="Sign Up">
</div>
```

Comment: what `text-left` is suppose to do?

Comment: What difference would this make?  How do you know the content isn't already wrapped in a `div`?  (Hint: The question doesn't show any of the relevant markup for that content.)